# Install Mesa to home folder and make applications use it from there

Tags: drivers, gpu

I'm trying to help debug an issue with Mesa and the llvm r600 shader compiler, and would prefer not to install the test compiles of these packages system wide.
My question therefore is: How can I install these two packages to my home folder and make applications use them from there?

I've tried to compile llvm with --prefix set to a subfolder of home, and then to compile mesa using --with-llvm-prefix to point to that installation folder of llvm. Both packages compile fine.

Nevertheless, when running applications with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path-to-mesa-install/lib/:path-to-llvm-install/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" 
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH="path-to-mesa-install/lib/dri"
```

I'm experiencing graphics issues in some applications (for instance the bloom effect is missing in Euro Truck Simulator), and other applications that are running fine with the same version of Mesa installed system wide refuse to start (for instance the Unigine benchmarks).

Therefore I think I'm missing something, but what?

I'd be grateful if someone could either link to or quickly write a step by step guide on how to use Mesa installed to a non-system wide path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian's X Strike Force has a comprehensive [guide to building MESA](https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/build-mesa.html) from source and running it without installing it (which effectively allows using it without installing it to a system path).

Comment: This old answer of yours isn't up to your current standards :) Could you please bring the relevant parts of the link here for all the usual reasons? Cheers.